# Three.js Get all meshes by name property value.

Tags: three.js

I have a simple Three.js scene in which i have generated some meshes. 
Some of these have name property = 'quadrant'.
I just want get all the meshes named 'quadrant' in any way.
i used *scene.getObjectByName("quadrant");* and it works but return me only the first element named 'quadrant' finded. how can i do?

Comment: You can have look at the [source code of this method](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/5360a81b8c557ed255e97b87c49e7d00b546b795/src/core/Object3D.js#L439) to see how it works under the hood and write your own one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i did some digging to clarify this for myself too. So, long story short, you wont be able to access all meshes using `getObjectByName` method. It doesn't work like class selector in css.
Three.JS documentation points out:

> .getObjectByName ( name : String ) -- 
>   Searches through the object's children and returns the first with a matching name.

So, you have 2 options:

- Give each mesh unique name
- traverse through scene's objects

I made code snippet with animation and material modification, because it wasn't clear what you want to achieve.

Example contains:

- How tu use `getObjectByName` method for one object to modify it's material
- How to traverse through scene's children and check if they have "quadrant" name

So, in short:

```
scene.traverse(function(child) {
  if (child.name === "quadrant") {
    child.material = ClassMaterial; //apply same material to all meshes
  }
});
```

Hope solution is clear, good luck.

More detailed example:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 50;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x00ff00
});

var UniceMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xffff00
});
var ClassMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x00ffff
});


for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  cube.name = "demo";
  cube.myid = j;
  cube.position.x = j * -2;
  cube.position.y = j - 2;
  cube.position.z = j / 100;
  scene.add(cube);
}

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  cube.name = "quadrant";
  cube.myid = i;
  cube.position.x = i * 2;
  cube.position.y = i + 2;
  cube.position.z = i / 100;
  scene.add(cube);
}

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  cube.name = "quadrant" + 1;
  cube.myid = i;
  cube.position.x = 0;
  cube.position.y = i * -4;
  cube.position.z = i / 100;
  scene.add(cube);
}


scene.traverse(function(child) {
  //if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
  if (child.name === "quadrant") {
    child.material = ClassMaterial;
    //console.log (child);
  }
  //child.material = ClassMaterial;
  //}
});

ObjectWithGetMethod = scene.getObjectByName("quadrant1");
ObjectWithGetMethod.material = UniceMaterial;

var animate = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  scene.traverse(function(cube) {
    if (cube.name === "demo") {
      cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
      cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    }
  });

  //despite you try to select  "quadrant" it animates last added cube:
  if (cube.name = "quadrant") {
    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
  }

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/90/three.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My first three.js app</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    canvas {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>


</body>

</html>
```